# Not able to use \MakeLowercase in \titlecap?

Tags: titlecaps

Here is the minimal code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\begin{document}
\MakeLowercase{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing} \\
\titlecap{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing}\\
\titlecap{\MakeLowercase{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What makes you think it should work? It won't and there are many reasons why it doesn't.

Comment: Kindly help me ,How to make first letter in uppercase and other than in lowercase letter in every word of a line @egreg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility...  Here, `\caselower` saves its result into `\thestring`.  You can do that quietly with `\caselower[q]{<string to process>}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{titlecaps, stringstrings}

\begin{document}
\caselower{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing} \\
\titlecap{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing}\\
\expandafter\titlecap\expandafter{\thestring}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, to get to the result directly

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{titlecaps, stringstrings}

\begin{document}
\caselower[q]{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing} 
\expandafter\titlecap\expandafter{\thestring}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If i comment \caselower{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing} \\
\titlecap{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing}\\ then third command not working 
\expandafter\titlecap\expandafter{\thestring}, I need only single output, anyway thank you so much for your kind reply. @Steven B. Segletes

Comment: @BikiTeron See my explanation, please.

Comment: Yes your coding is very intresting, its working thank you so much for your effort @@Steven B. Segletes

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xtitlecap}{O{}m}
 {
  \teron_xtitlecap:nf { #1 } { \tl_lower_case:n { #2 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \teron_xtitlecap:nn
 {
  \titlecap[#1]{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \teron_xtitlecap:nn { nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MakeLowercase{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing}

\xtitlecap{LAtex foR doCumenT seTTing}

\end{document}
```

[image]